# Open New Outlook email window on clinet machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, outlook

I have  a C# MVC application. I am using Outlook Interlop to create and open new mail through the application with contents and attachments pre-populated.

I get the desired functionality when I run the application locally on my development machine.

When I deploy the same application to server (2012 R2), the outlook new email window does not open on the client side.

1. Is is possible to open new outlook email window on client machine with the interlop code running on server. (Every user of the application has Outlook installed on their machine).
2. I have just installed Outlook 2013 on the server. Is there anything else I need to do on the server to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been struggling a lot to make this work.

Are there any alternative solutions to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that works locally on your development machine

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        oMsg.Subject = "subject something";
        oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        oMsg.HTMLBody = "text body"; //Here comes your body;
        
        oMsg.Display(false);

Answer (score 2):

No, firstly, Outlook cannot run in a service such as IIS.

Even if it could, it would still be displayed on the server side.

You can dynamically generate an EML (MIME) message on the server. When the user on the client side downloads it, Outlook will display it. If you want the message to be displayed unsent, make sure you include X-Unsent MIME header (set its value to 1).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you pls provide me some code sample for the same.

Comment: I do not have anything I can share. EML is just a text file - you can open it in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Code running on the server makes stuff happen on the server. It works on your dev machine because it's both client and server, it won't work on other people's machines. In addition to that, I believe the Office Interop stuff specifically says it's not for use on a server (for both technical and legal reasons).

If you want to pop up a message pre-populated with some values on a client machine, you do have the option of the [mailto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Email_links) link, but I believe it is only plain text with no attachments.